# Analysis of Complex Integration for different $m$

Tags: complex-analysis

Say we have parameterized and integrated a complex function $z^m$ over a circle of radius $1$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and get

$$\frac{1}{m+1}(e^{i2\pi(m+1)}-1)$$ and say that it is equal to $0$ if $m\neq -1$, but is equal to $2\pi i $ if $m=-1$.

The first equality is clear by the equation. But the second quality just gives $$\frac{1}{0}(1-1)=\frac{1}{0}(0).$$ What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing that the antiderivative of $z^m$ is $$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{z^{m+1}}{m+1} & \text{if } m\neq -1\\\\
\ln(z) & \text{if }m=-1
\end{cases}$$
You just blindly applied the formula of the $m\neq -1$ case.

Comment: where is $2\pi i$ coming from

Comment: You have skipped a vital part of the problem. Before you solve for the antiderivative, try setting $m=-1$ and simplifying. The problem should be much nicer.

Comment: I see. The formula derived can classify the points not equal to 1, but we can go back and put $z^{-1}$ in the integral and just evaluate it as normal to get the value.

Comment: We get $i\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta = 2\pi i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the contour integral around the unit circle $\gamma(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$
$$\oint_\gamma z^m\;dz$$
we get the parametrized integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{i\theta})^m \frac{dz}{d\theta}\,d\theta$$
Note that the change of variables $z= e^{i\theta}$ means that $\dfrac{dz}{d\theta}=ie^{i\theta}$ so we get
$$i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(m+1)\theta}\,d\theta$$
The antiderivative of $e^{ax}$ is 
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{e^{ax}}{a}+C & \text{if }a\neq 0\\\\
x+C & \text{if }a=0 \text{ (since $e^{0x}=e^0=1$)}
\end{cases}$$
Therefore the result is
$$\begin{cases}
i\cdot\dfrac{e^{i(m+1)\theta}}{i(m+1)}\biggr|_0^{2\pi}=\dfrac{e^{2\pi i(m+1)}-1}{m+1}=0 & \text{if }m\neq -1\\\\
i\cdot \theta\;\biggr|_0^{2\pi}=2\pi i -0 = 2\pi i & \text{if }m=-1
\end{cases}$$